# Azure service principal name for Linked services

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have few linked services used to copy data from on premise server to Azure BLOB and then loading that data into Azure DB using ADF pipeline, these linked services are using a user account to authenticate, I want to replace this user account with a Service Principal name. Is it possible? If yes then how.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, indeed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#linked-service-properties

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it is possible.I checked [blob storage linked service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#service-principal-authentication) and [azure sql db linked service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#service-principal-authentication) documents,then all support service principal authenticate ways. You could choose that way when you create linked services:

[image]